# Node tree adding profiles on some edges of a plane

Tags: node-editor, edges, geometry, select

Trying to get a node tree capable of adding different profiles along specific sides of plane objects.

[image: The result should look like this. Profiles are darker color.]

This current rendering was obtained by copying edges in edit mode then making distinct objects  from the edge copies. The corresponding "object info" was brought in a node tree, then Mesh to curve, curve to mesh with profiles corresponding to the desired shape.

I am now unsuccessfully trying to get a better node trees that would simplify the process, make it swiftly applicable and adjustable on various plane objects. I intend to bring at least two plane's 'object info' in one tree and then nodes would select specific edges and apply corresponding profiles to them.
How can that be done ?
Your suggestions are welcome.
Merci !